# Angular calling controller method from directive with parameters inside link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has a link function something like:

```
 scope: {
                target: '@',
                fooFunction: '&'
            },
link:
   scope.$apply(attrs.fooFunction);
var fooValue= scope.fooFunction(data,scope.target);
```

in my controller i have defined this function as :

```
$scope.fooFunction= function (data, target) {
//some code here
}
```

When I use this in the html, I write like this:

```
<div some-directive  foo-Function="fooFunction(ctrl.data,'hardCoded')"  target="actualValue"></div>
```

where I am using myController as ctrl.

My question is that even when I am passing the value as scope.target it always picks the hardCoded value.
Is there any way I can pass the value from the scope.target instead of the hard coded value?

Answer (score 1):

As you have mention target as `@` so you need to use `{{}}` to evaluate that attribute value, which would be treated as one way binding.

Like you could have value inside your controller `actualValue` variable and then you could bind that like `target="{{ctrl.actualValue}}"`

**Markup**

```
<div some-directive 
  foo-function="fooFunction(ctrl.data,'hardCoded')"
  target="{{ctrl.actualValue}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies if my question confused you , my question is that : From my directive I am calling :  var fooValue= scope.fooFunction(data,scope.target); but the value is passed as 'hardcoded' and not the value from the function.

Comment: @Raghav the answer which I gave, is what you wanted?

Comment: please see my comment above

Comment: Sorry let me explain again. So if you see my directive I have this method call : var fooValue= scope.fooFunction(data,scope.target);  which calls the controller method. In the controller function $scope.fooFunction= function (data, target)  I get the values as target ='hardcoded' but I am passing scope.target which has the value 'actualValue'

Comment: @Raghav inside directive you are using `controllerAs`?

Comment: I think OP confuses purpose of `fooFunction: '&'` bindings. He doesn't need it in this case.

Comment: I mean if directives needs some data from controller, then one needs to pass it using attributes and not write getter function like `fooFunction: '&'`.